# .submit() not submitting form after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set a delay when a user clicks submit on a form before it submits.. I have an image that displays to test the click event, and it works fine, but the form does never submit...

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form class='loginForm1' action='verify_credentials.php' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log into Answer Tree</legend>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input class='inputs' name='username' type="text" placeholder="Enter username...">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input class='inputs' name='password' type="text" placeholder="Enter password...">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
        <button id='submit' type='button' class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".containerLogin img").hide();
});

$(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $(".containerLogin img").show();
        setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);
    });
});

function submitForm() {
    $(".loginForm1").submit();
}
```

I got this error message:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function`

Comment: well, `.delay(2000).$('.loginForm1')` is wrong syntax for one, and two, .delay() only delays animations. You should use setTimeout as suggested in your question title.

Comment: You have two opening `<fieldset>` tags, and fieldset should be inside `<form>`.

Comment: srry added wrong code... here is what i have been having trouble with

Comment: And is there errors in the console?

Comment: I just changed the fieldsets... still no luck

Comment: this is what i am getting, Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Comment: PUT THAT INFO IN YOUR QUESTION TO START!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the naming of your button, it overrides the submit() handler.

Rename the button to

```
<button id='btnSubmit' type = 'button' ...
```

And change your selector to match.

Comment: yup that did it lol thanks will accept as answer when.. :)